# Using the php method file_get_contents I'm pulling an entire webpage to my website

Tags: php, javascript, dom

Here's my code:

```
<?php 
$html = file_get_contents("http://aaaaaa.bbbbb.com/thisstuff");

$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($html);

var_dump ($dom->getElementsByTagName('div'));

  for ($i = 0; $i < $items->length; $i++)
         echo $items->item($i)->nodeValue . "<br/>";
?>
```

The only div class on the page i need to retrieve is:

class="fap index" id="canvas"

How should i got about this, perhaps using document.getElementById?

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use:

```
$canvas = $dom->getElementById('canvas');
```

Not sure what you want to do with the DOMElement object that would be set to `$canvas`, but you can obviously look at the documentation for DOMElement to see the available methods on it.

http://php.net/manual/en/class.domelement.php

Comment: I don't get anything and i lose all the content.

Comment: What do you mean you don't get anything?  What does var_dump($canvas, $dom) produce?

Comment: object(DOMElement)#3 (0) { } object(DOMDocument)#1 (0) { }

Comment: OK. So what are you actually trying to do with `$canvas`?

Comment: I forgot to: $canvas = $canvas->nodeValue;
echo $canvas;   it worked.. thanks

Comment: Is it possible to pull the styles through for that div too?

Comment: @Supplement If the styles are in-line styles (i.e. within `style="somecss: somevalue;"`), you could parse them out with `$canvas->getAttribute('style')`. If there is a stylesheet with the styles, you will be out of luck, as that is not part of the DOMDocument at all.